# CSV data (unkown format) to XML data (fixed format) via business classes. Is using reflection a good idea?

Tags: c#, xml, reflection, csv, business-objects

I am working on a library that builds fairly large XML files (e-commerce offers).

I use business classes (such as ProductInfo, PriceInfo etc.) and I generate the resulting XML out of these.

My latest task is to implement functionality that allows to generate this XML out of CSV input files.

The CSV files do not have any predefined format and it is user's task (we provide an application that allows them to do that) to map all the CSV columns into their respective counterparts in our fixed XML format.

So basically their job is to assign each column to one of my bussiness classes fields: "all data from this column goes into ProductInfo.ShortDescription etc.".

Our format is likely to change in future - it keeps on being updated and extended - and so I would like to make my implementation as generic as possible.

The solution I considered is following:

- the library returns names of all the available / required fields
- our user maps CSV columns to those fields
- I implement a custom attribute (containing a field name - string) and mark all the fields in my business classes with it. So once they've mapped all the columns and submitted the data in CSV, my library starts creating ProductInfos etc. assigning input values to  fields, identified by the attribute name. This would be done by reflection.

Is this a good idea? I have some concerns regarding performance (I know that reflection is slow), although I'm not sure how much of an issue that would be. Is there any other issues I should be aware of? Are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set up a web service to handle these for the end user?  If you make changes to your business objects, which are exposed through the service, the schema for the WSDL service will automatically update.  This will give you the ability to strongly type your data through a schema automatically.

Comment: Even though those XML files will be sent out afterwards no doubt - it is a desktop library and application, and I have to do it locally nevertheless. I don't have a say as for the project architecture, which is admittedly suboptimal in many aspects :) (not just imo)